# tensorflow profile explanation

Tags: tensorflow, keras

[image]

I use tensorflow profile to test the inference of my model and here is the profile details. I find that there are `0,1,2,3`, four numbers where `1` and `2` are filled with blank. So what is the meaning of 0-4 and why there are blanks in `1` and `2`. 
The machine has 80 cores and does it mean that the inference course only occupy 4 cores of them ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that each row corresponds to each worker thread to run operators.
 So your inference processing only occupies 4 cores as you say. 
Tensorflow uses multi-threads when

1. There are some independent graph parts.
2. There is a operator using multi-threads.

So you can use multi-core effectively, if your graph have many independent graph parts.

In the following code, the graph has many independent graph parts. Therefore the number of the rows in profiler matches to "inter_op_parallelism_threads".

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(inter_op_parallelism_threads=5, intra_op_parallelism_threads=1)

with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    list_r = []

    for i in range(80):
        r = tf.random_normal(shape=[100, 100])
        list_r.append(r)

    v = tf.add_n(list_r)


global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()
hook = tf.train.ProfilerHook(save_steps=1)
increment_global = global_step.assign_add(1)


with tf.train.SingularMonitoredSession(hooks=[hook], config=config) as sess:
    sess.run([v, increment_global])
```

If you want to know the detail of ConfigProto, you can get information from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto